# How to interpret the differences in estimated variances?

Tags: r, variance, garch, moving-window, volatility

I estimated the variance of Bitcoin in several ways using the `var` command in R, and within a GARCH model. I get series that look a bit similar, but the y-axis gives different results. Is this normal?

[image]

Here, the variance is estimated within a GARCH model (in red) and as the realized variance (in black), i.e the sum of past squared returns (over 30 days).

Comment: Given the different scales (ranges of $Y$ axis), the two graphs are a little tricky to compare. It would be interesting to see a plot where both series are shown together (in different colors).

Comment: @RichardHardy I've edited the post !

Comment: Did you probably mean sum of past *squared* returns? But then again, if you used `var`, this is not the sum of past squared returns, it is the variance of past returns.

Comment: Yes I've used the sum of past squared  ! The ```var``` measure is even more different with the GARCH modelized variance !

Comment: This does not sound plausible. The sums of squared returns should be about 30 times higher than the variance, because variance is the sum divided by 30-1. So GARCH and variance should be on the same scale, but sums of squared returns should be on a different scale (much higher). Unless you are using different data frequencies for different measures of volatility, that is.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is normal. A GARCH(1,1) model
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \mu_t+\varepsilon_t, \\
\mu_t &= ..., \\
\varepsilon_t &= \sigma_t z_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 \varepsilon_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2, \\
z_t &\sim i.i.N(0,1)
\end{aligned}
often has $\beta_1$ close to $0.9$ (and $\alpha_1$ close to $0.1$) which makes it not so sensitive to what happens locally as in your 30-day rolling variance. Thus, you see more variation in your rolling variance than in GARCH but still about the same overall level of variance in both.